Core Data Export / Import
My app manages data with Core Data. I would like to add an export and import function to the app.
The export seems to work so far (at least a .sqlite file is saved). However, when I want to import the file, it is only greyed out and I cannot select it. Do I need to change anything in the code? Or set the permission for accessing files in the app settings in XCode (if so, what do I have to select in the iOS target properties? I haven't found anything suitable while looking)?
// export funktion
    func exportDatabase(completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        let storeCoordinator = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
        guard let store = storeCoordinator.persistentStores.first else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        let exportURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("BookCatalog.sqlite")
        
        do {
            try storeCoordinator.migratePersistentStore(store, to: exportURL, options: nil, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
            completion(exportURL)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to export database: \(error)")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }

    // import funktion
    func importDatabase(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let storeCoordinator = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
        guard let store = storeCoordinator.persistentStores.first else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try storeCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: store.url!, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
            try storeCoordinator.replacePersistentStore(at: store.url!, destinationOptions: nil, withPersistentStoreFrom: url, sourceOptions: nil, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
            completion(true)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to import database: \(error)")
            completion(false)
        }
    }

Tried it with the Code above. But I cannot select a file when I try to import

The code you have posted has nothing to do with selecting the file.
